# Why my interrupt in AVR does not work correctly?

Tags: c++, interrupt, avr

EDIT: IT'S WORKING

I'm programming Atmega8 communication with PC. I use Treminal v1.9b to send and receive "messages". Here's my code:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_char(char letter)
{
    if( bit_is_set(UCSRA, UDRE) )
    {
        _delay_ms(10);
        UDR=letter;
        loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, TXC);
    }
}

volatile char what = 'x';

int main(void)
{
    DDRC |= (1<<PC0);
    DDRC |= (1<<PC1);
    DDRC |= (1<<PC2);

    UBRRL = 12;//4800 1mhz
    UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN)|(1<<RXCIE);
    UCSRC = (1<<URSEL)|(1<<UCSZ1)|(1<<UCSZ0);

    sei();

    PORTC ^= (1<<PC1);

    while(1)
    {
        print_char(what);
        PORTC ^= (1<<PC0);
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{
    what = UDR;
    PORTC ^= (1<<PC2);
}
```

After switch on uC, in the console (Terminal v1.9b) 'x' appear, after trying to send anything, the 'x' stops popping up. It's like the program hung or the interrupt did not return to the main program. (after sending anything to the uC, the given value should be displaying in the console).

When the uC is switch on, led at PC1 is shining, at PC0 is winking, at PC2 is dark. After send any char to uC: led at PC0 is dark, at PC1 is shining, at PC2 is dark. As though the funcktion ISR() doesn't start.

Where is the problem?

.iss file:

```
usb2.elf:     file format elf32-avr

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .text         00000106  00000000  00000000  00000074  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000002  00800060  00000106  0000017a  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:   29 c0           rjmp    .+82        ; 0x54 <__ctors_end>
   2:   00 00           nop
   4:   3a c0           rjmp    .+116       ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
   6:   00 00           nop
   8:   38 c0           rjmp    .+112       ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
   a:   00 00           nop
   c:   36 c0           rjmp    .+108       ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
   e:   00 00           nop
  10:   34 c0           rjmp    .+104       ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  12:   00 00           nop
  14:   32 c0           rjmp    .+100       ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  16:   00 00           nop
  18:   30 c0           rjmp    .+96        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  1a:   00 00           nop
  1c:   2e c0           rjmp    .+92        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  1e:   00 00           nop
  20:   2c c0           rjmp    .+88        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  22:   00 00           nop
  24:   2a c0           rjmp    .+84        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  26:   00 00           nop
  28:   28 c0           rjmp    .+80        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  2a:   00 00           nop
  2c:   55 c0           rjmp    .+170       ; 0xd8 <__vector_11>
  2e:   00 00           nop
  30:   24 c0           rjmp    .+72        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  32:   00 00           nop
  34:   22 c0           rjmp    .+68        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  36:   00 00           nop
  38:   20 c0           rjmp    .+64        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  3a:   00 00           nop
  3c:   1e c0           rjmp    .+60        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  3e:   00 00           nop
  40:   1c c0           rjmp    .+56        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  42:   00 00           nop
  44:   1a c0           rjmp    .+52        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  46:   00 00           nop
  48:   18 c0           rjmp    .+48        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  4a:   00 00           nop
  4c:   16 c0           rjmp    .+44        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
  4e:   00 00           nop
  50:   14 c0           rjmp    .+40        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
    ...

00000054 <__ctors_end>:
  54:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  56:   1f be           out 0x3f, r1    ; 63
  58:   cf e5           ldi r28, 0x5F   ; 95
  5a:   d4 e0           ldi r29, 0x04   ; 4
  5c:   de bf           out 0x3e, r29   ; 62
  5e:   cd bf           out 0x3d, r28   ; 61

00000060 <__do_copy_data>:
  60:   10 e0           ldi r17, 0x00   ; 0
  62:   a0 e6           ldi r26, 0x60   ; 96
  64:   b0 e0           ldi r27, 0x00   ; 0
  66:   e6 e0           ldi r30, 0x06   ; 6
  68:   f1 e0           ldi r31, 0x01   ; 1
  6a:   02 c0           rjmp    .+4         ; 0x70 <.do_copy_data_start>

0000006c <.do_copy_data_loop>:
  6c:   05 90           lpm r0, Z+
  6e:   0d 92           st  X+, r0

00000070 <.do_copy_data_start>:
  70:   a2 36           cpi r26, 0x62   ; 98
  72:   b1 07           cpc r27, r17
  74:   d9 f7           brne    .-10        ; 0x6c <.do_copy_data_loop>
  76:   0c d0           rcall   .+24        ; 0x90 <main>
  78:   44 c0           rjmp    .+136       ; 0x102 <_exit>

0000007a <__bad_interrupt>:
  7a:   c2 cf           rjmp    .-124       ; 0x0 <__vectors>

0000007c <_Z10print_charc>:
  7c:   5d 9b           sbis    0x0b, 5 ; 11
  7e:   07 c0           rjmp    .+14        ; 0x8e <_Z10print_charc+0x12>
  80:   e4 ec           ldi r30, 0xC4   ; 196
  82:   f9 e0           ldi r31, 0x09   ; 9
  84:   31 97           sbiw    r30, 0x01   ; 1
  86:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0x84 <_Z10print_charc+0x8>
  88:   8c b9           out 0x0c, r24   ; 12
  8a:   5e 9b           sbis    0x0b, 6 ; 11
  8c:   fe cf           rjmp    .-4         ; 0x8a <_Z10print_charc+0xe>
  8e:   08 95           ret

00000090 <main>:
  90:   1f 93           push    r17
  92:   cf 93           push    r28
  94:   df 93           push    r29
  96:   a0 9a           sbi 0x14, 0 ; 20
  98:   a1 9a           sbi 0x14, 1 ; 20
  9a:   a2 9a           sbi 0x14, 2 ; 20
  9c:   8c e0           ldi r24, 0x0C   ; 12
  9e:   89 b9           out 0x09, r24   ; 9
  a0:   88 e9           ldi r24, 0x98   ; 152
  a2:   8a b9           out 0x0a, r24   ; 10
  a4:   86 e8           ldi r24, 0x86   ; 134
  a6:   80 bd           out 0x20, r24   ; 32
  a8:   85 b7           in  r24, 0x35   ; 53
  aa:   81 60           ori r24, 0x01   ; 1
  ac:   85 bf           out 0x35, r24   ; 53
  ae:   8b b7           in  r24, 0x3b   ; 59
  b0:   80 64           ori r24, 0x40   ; 64
  b2:   8b bf           out 0x3b, r24   ; 59
  b4:   78 94           sei
  b6:   85 b3           in  r24, 0x15   ; 21
  b8:   92 e0           ldi r25, 0x02   ; 2
  ba:   89 27           eor r24, r25
  bc:   85 bb           out 0x15, r24   ; 21
  be:   11 e0           ldi r17, 0x01   ; 1
  c0:   c8 ea           ldi r28, 0xA8   ; 168
  c2:   d1 e6           ldi r29, 0x61   ; 97
  c4:   80 91 60 00     lds r24, 0x0060
  c8:   d9 df           rcall   .-78        ; 0x7c <_Z10print_charc>
  ca:   85 b3           in  r24, 0x15   ; 21
  cc:   81 27           eor r24, r17
  ce:   85 bb           out 0x15, r24   ; 21
  d0:   ce 01           movw    r24, r28
  d2:   01 97           sbiw    r24, 0x01   ; 1
  d4:   f1 f7           brne    .-4         ; 0xd2 <main+0x42>
  d6:   f6 cf           rjmp    .-20        ; 0xc4 <main+0x34>

000000d8 <__vector_11>:
  d8:   1f 92           push    r1
  da:   0f 92           push    r0
  dc:   0f b6           in  r0, 0x3f    ; 63
  de:   0f 92           push    r0
  e0:   11 24           eor r1, r1
  e2:   8f 93           push    r24
  e4:   9f 93           push    r25
  e6:   85 b3           in  r24, 0x15   ; 21
  e8:   94 e0           ldi r25, 0x04   ; 4
  ea:   89 27           eor r24, r25
  ec:   85 bb           out 0x15, r24   ; 21
  ee:   8c b1           in  r24, 0x0c   ; 12
  f0:   80 93 60 00     sts 0x0060, r24
  f4:   9f 91           pop r25
  f6:   8f 91           pop r24
  f8:   0f 90           pop r0
  fa:   0f be           out 0x3f, r0    ; 63
  fc:   0f 90           pop r0
  fe:   1f 90           pop r1
 100:   18 95           reti

00000102 <_exit>:
 102:   f8 94           cli

00000104 <__stop_program>:
 104:   ff cf           rjmp    .-2         ; 0x104 <__stop_program>
```

Comment: I don't know avr, so it's a comment rather than an answer, but I suspect you've got to clear the pending interrupt flag for your USART Rx IRQ, if that's the case, and you're not doing it, it will keep reentering the interrupt context.

Comment: How to clear this flag?

Comment: Check the datasheet and manual, it'll tell you there.

Comment: Oh of course, I forgot about the datasheet. Thanks

Comment: @Colin: No, you are wrong! AVR USART clears the irq flag by reading the uart data register automatically. No need to manually clear irq flags. For RXC, it can't be cleared manually as the fifo remains full ( unread data ) which will keep the irq flag set!

Comment: Why you are manipulating RXC in irq handler? Makes no sense for me. In addition, you switch of RX interrupt here so that you only receive a single char and switch of the irq. Is this intended?

Comment: Are you sure you stop receiving any data? Not receiving the last sent byte (space, line feed or any other empty symbol)? replace `|=` by `=` in `UCSRB |= ...` and `UCSRC |= `... especially UCSRC, because it cannot be read simply at atmega8. `UCSRA &= ~(1<<RXC);` in the interrupt has no sense. Remove it. `UCSRB &= ~(1<<RXCIE);` disables the receive interrupt, therefore no more bytes will be received except the very first byte.

Comment: @AterLux I updated code above. I used a LED's to see what is happening. So, led at PC1 is shining, at PC0 is winking, at PC2 is dark. After send any char to uC: led at PC0 is dark, at PC1 is shining, at PC2 is dark. As though the funcktion ISR() doesn't start.

Comment: Reporting state of PC1 is worthless, because you are enabling it before while(1) and that's all. Why do you use delay_ms in print char function?

Comment: I know, about PC1, it's "control" led to see that everything is allright. But it doesn't change the fact that the interrupt doesn't work.  I'm using _delay_ms() in the function, because during higher freauency the sending doesn't work very well.

Comment: Does your ISR works fine when you comment `print_char(what);` line in while(1)? I mean led state changes whenever you send character in serial?

Comment: After comment print_char(what) in while(1) led on PC0 and PC1 is shining, PC2 is dark.

Comment: Even when you are sending characters via terminal?

Comment: I mean after comment and after send anything to uC

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking about sending (PC to uC) characters changing state of PC2? Or it's dark from start and doesn't change when you send character. It should change state every single received character. As someone mentioned use `|=` instead of `=` when initializing registers. Change delay_ms in while to 500 ms to be sure you see changing LED state PC0.

Comment: Yes, PC2 is dark since start, after send char is still dark. I changed time in _delay_ms, PC0 is changing.

Comment: Are you sure you have selected a correct MCU in the project settings? Can you provide the disassemble of generated binaries (.lss file)?

Comment: Yes, I selected good mcu. The .iss file is above, at the code section.

Comment: I have just seen that interrupts for timers doesn't work very well too.

Comment: It might be problem with compilator?

Comment: Allright, I have changed an environment and it's working. Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, in the generated vector table:

```asm
00000000 <__vectors>:
   0:   29 c0           rjmp    .+82        ; 0x54 <__ctors_end>
   2:   00 00           nop
   4:   3a c0           rjmp    .+116       ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
   6:   00 00           nop
   8:   38 c0           rjmp    .+112       ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
   a:   00 00           nop
...
  2c:   55 c0           rjmp    .+170       ; 0xd8 <__vector_11>
  2e:   00 00           nop
```

each interrupt vector uses 2 words: one for `rjmp` and one filled with `nop`.

Thus 12th vector is located at addrees 0x002C (or 0x16 word address).

In the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf) in *table 18*, section *Interrupt Vectors
in ATmega8* at page *46* you can see, in ATmega8 for each vector only one word is allocated (it is enough for `rjmp` instruction, which allows to jump to any address within 4Kwords address space).

Thus, the *USART, RXC* vector should be placed at 0x0B word address (or 0x0016 byte address).

In other words, you have incorrect setup for the compiling environment, probably you have selected wrong CPU.

When actual interrupt happens, vector at(byte-address `0x0016` is executed:

```
  16:   00 00           nop
  18:   30 c0           rjmp    .+96        ; 0x7a <__bad_interrupt>
```

causing skipping of `nop` operation and jumping to `__bad_interrupt` label:

```
0000007a <__bad_interrupt>:
  7a:   c2 cf           rjmp    .-124       ; 0x0 <__vectors>
```

which causes the program to halt